# Can I ignore queries about extendedproperty?

Tags: ssms, scripting, schema-copy

I want to reuse the structure of a database in a new project. So using **SSMS** I use **Generate Script** and in settings I set to generate **schema only**.

In the result there are too many queries about extendedproperty. Is there any important data or settings in these queries or I can completely **igonre** them and only reuse queries on database tables and fields to start a similar project?

And if they ar unnecessary how can I use **"generate script"** without them?

sample query:

```
EXEC sys.sp_dropextendedproperty @name=N'CollatingOrder' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'billboard', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'url'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify this behaviour by changing the scripting options:

```
Tools -> Options -> SQL Server explorer -> Scripting -> Script extended properties
```

[image]

> Is there any important data or settings in these queries or I can completely ignore them...

**It depends.**

DBA's and developers can use extended properties to save information about database objects. If you're scripting other dba's objects you could loose information about them.

Have a look at this articles on MSSQLTips:

[**Working with SQL Server Extended Properties**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5384/working-with-sql-server-extended-properties/)

<sub>Quoted from doc</sub>

> Extended Properties can be created for the below database objects, but
>   in this tip, we are going to focus on column level Extended
>   Properties.
>
> - Database
> - Stored Procedures
> - User-defined Functions
> - Table
> - Table Column
> - Table Index
> - Views
> - Rules
> - Triggers
> - Constraints

> Extended Properties can be used to:
>
> - Specify a caption for a table, view, or column.
> - Specify a display mask for a column.
> - Display a format of a column, define edit mask for a date column, define number of decimals, etc.
> - Specify formatting rules for displaying the data in a column.
> - Describe a specific database objects for all users.